# MODE Function for returning most frequently occurring word (string)-Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am working on a Google sheet which allows users to input their suggestions in a table. In this case, I have asked my team to input their favourite animal suggestions.

[image: Input Table]

In order to save time, I would like the most frequently occuring input to be shown in the yellow cell. I first tried to get the MODE for a single column(assuming column A).

```
    =UNIQUE(QUERY({A:A,ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A))},"select Col1 where 
    Col2="&MAX(arrayformula(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)))))
```

I then tried to modify this function to work for multiple columns:

```
    =UNIQUE(QUERY({A73:E77,ArrayFormula(COUNTIF(A73:E77,A73:E77))},"select Col1 where Col2="&MAX(arrayformula(COUNTIF(A73:E77,A73:E77)))))
```

This function did not work.

Can someone please help me correct my function so that I can return the MODE for the most common animal suggestion in my table.

Please let me know if something is not clear.

Thank you :)

Comment: why tag this as excel / excel-formula when it is clear it is for google sheets only...

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search brought me to this link which should answer your question.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3397-excel-find-mode-for-text.html

I tried to apply it to how you are setting up your data in a table format.  However, I could only get it to work if your animal list is in a single column.

I applied the formula from the site to a single column, and it works.  The formula is:

```
    =INDEX($B$2:$B$17,MODE(MATCH($B$2:$B$17,$B$2:$B$17,0)))
```

Here is the result as it appeared:
[image]

If the name of the person who submitted each animal is important, maybe you can just include that in the column next to each submission.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @PaulZaino thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this function does not work in Google sheets & only works for one column. As stated above, I need a function which will return the most frequently occurring word or string in multiple columns.